# Извращенный порядок слов на многих сайтах

Tags: порядок-слов

В последние года два я часто вижу извращенный порядок слов на многих сайтах.

Примеры:

1.

Написано: "Крупный пожар случился в центре Москвы"

Правильно: "В центре Москвы случился крупный пожар"

2.

Написано: "Самолет разбился во время тушения лесного пожара во Франции"

Правильно: "Во время тушения лесного пожара во Франции разбился самолет"

3.

Написано: "Бизнес-джет едва не разбился в Пулково"

Правильно: "В Пулково едва не разбился бизнес-джет"

Кто-нибудь знает, почему на многих сайтах появился такой безграмотный извращенный стиль?

Почему это кажется извращенным? Потому что в тексте самое важное ставится в конце предложения. Например, в предлождении "Бизнес-джет едва не разбился в Пулково" самое важное то, что это было в Пулково. Т.е. это предложение означает примерно следующее: "Бизнес-джет где только не летал, нигде с ним ни чего не случалось. Ни в Риме, ни в Париже, ни в Лондоне. И где вы думаете он чуть не разбился? В Пулково". Порядок слов, который этот смысл передает, мне и кажется извращенным.
А на самом деле имелось в виду следующее: "В Пулково произошло важное событие, а именно, чуть не разбился бизнес-джет". Вот этот смысл передается предложением "В Пулково едва не разбился бизнес-джет".

[Вот единственный линк](https://www.sinykova.ru/spravochnik-rozental/styli_xlii/) с правилами на эту тему:

> Определяющим фактором расположения слов в предложении является
>   целенаправленность высказывания, его коммуникативное задание. С ним
>   связано так называемое **актуальное членение** высказывания, которое предполагает движение мысли от известного,
>   знакомого к неизвестному, новому: первое (основа высказывания) обычно
>   заключено в начальной части предложения, второе (ядро высказывания) –
>   в его конечной части.

Других ссылок на авторитетные источники у меня нет. Поэтому пытаюсь найти ответ здесь.

Интересно также узнать, какие различия в смысле Вы видите в зависимости от порядка слов. Например, что Вам говорит *"Бизнес-джет едва не разбился в Пулково"* и *"В Пулково едва не разбился бизнес-джет"*.

Comment: Эти примеры из текстов или заголовков? Какого рода эти многие сайты? Или это явление Вы не можете описать как системное? И последнее: Правильный порядок, он какой?

Comment: @shampar: Это примеры из заголовков Ленты.ру. Но я такое вижу на разных сайтах. Мне кажется, что это системное явление, т.к. в основном встречаю это на новостных сайтах. На других сайтах (услуги, продажа, справочная информация) таких режущих глаз предложений я не видел. И я не говорил, что есть правильный или неправильный порядок. В русском языке допускается почти любой порядок. Я имею в виду, что стало появляться много заголовков, где порядок слов передает совсем не тот смысл, который автор вложил в текст после такого заголовка.

Comment: «Не говорил, что есть правильный...»? Как в каждой строчке только точки, так в каждом примере «Правильно». Так как же объяснить это Правильное?

Comment: @shampar: Давайте проще. Вы просто скажите, что по Вашему мнение хотел сказать автор для кажого из приведенных примеров, для обоих порядков слов.

Comment: Вопрос не актуальный, хоть и изменён; ответы даны, и они приняты.

Comment: @shampar: Приняты только в смысле приняты к сведению. Объяснения хорошего я, к сожалению, не получил. Но спасибо всем, т.к. каждый старался свою точку зрения объяснить.

Comment: Объясню свою. Ваш Вопрос тоже принят к сведению: ни один из уточняющих вопросов из комментария не нашёл отражения в правке Вопроса, которая могла бы сделать его самодостаточным. Нужно видеть и учитывать разницу между фразами текста и фразами отдельными. Отсюда и правила — не по теме приведённых примеров.

Answer (score 9):

Новостные сайты используют такой порядок слов, чтобы сразу захватывать внимание читателя. Скучающий взгляд скользнёт по словам "В центре Москвы..." и пойдёт дальше, тогда как слова "Крупный пожар..." сразу привлекут внимание. С другими вашими примерами то же самое.

Кстати, не вижу в ваших примерах ничего извращённого, с точки зрения русского языка это совершенно нормальные фразы. Порядок слов в данном случае подчёркивает важные моменты, ничего извращённого в таком приёме нет.

Comment: Скучающий взгляд ищет как раз конец предложения, т.к. именно там стоит самое важное. "Самолет разбился во время тушения" значит, что самое важное - это не то, что самолет разбился, а как именно разбился. Такой порядок означает примерно следующее: "Ну и как этот самолет разбился? А он разбился во время тушения пожара". Порядо слов, который такой смысл закладывает, и кажется мне извращенным. Если автор имеет в виду "При тушении пожара произошел несчатный случай, разбился самолет", то и порядок должен быть другой: "При тушении пожара разбился самолет".

Comment: @Fedor Gromov, как это вы себе представляете? Как можно найти конец предложения не прочитав начало? Искать точку, не обращая внимания на буквы, а потом начинать от точки назад читать? И насчёт того, что самое важное всегда в конце предложения, это вы уж совсем в фантазии ударились.

Comment: Но при этом Вы сами используете именно такой порядок слов, который я  считаю корректным :) Вы же не пишете в таком стиле, как в моих примерах, которые я считаю направильными. Почему Вы не пишете, например, *Важные моменты подчёркивает в данном случае порядок слов*?

Comment: @Fedor Gromov, не использую, потому что я не журналист. В обычной речи такое выделение выглядело бы странным. В литературном тексте разные приёмы использую, хотя именно этот типичен всё-таки для журналистики, причём для не очень качественной журналистики. Для желтухи скорее.

Answer (score 4):

1) **Извращенный порядок слов? Неужели в прямом значении?**

Из словаря: **ИЗВРАЩЁННЫЙ**, 1. Искажённый. И-ое толкование. И. смысл. 2. Отклоняющийся от естественной нормы; ненормальный, противоестественный. И-ые вкусы. И-ые инстинкты.

Нет, это  не извращенный порядок слов, а неправильное толкование понятия "порядок слов".

2) Как известно, порядок слов в простом предложении соответствует схеме **тема — рема, предмет — сообщение о предмете**. Эти две части предложения составляют две интонационные фразы восходяще-нисходящего тона.

Поэтому весь вопрос  состоит в том, **что в каждом случае журналист считает темой, а что ремой.** Это его форма подачи материала, которая определяет расстановку логических (фразовых) ударений. **И при чем тут английский язык, я тоже не понимаю.**

3) ***Крупный пожар случился в центре Москвы.*** Тема — крупные пожары. Сообщение — место пожара (центр большого города).

***Самолет разбился во время тушения лесного пожара во Франции***. Тема — крушение самолёта. Сообщение — при каких обстоятельствах.

4) Разберем подробно

***Бизнес-джЕт едва не разбИлся в Пулково.*** Тема — самолет бизнес-джет, сообщение — инцидент с самолетом **такого класса.**

**Почему журналист сделал темой название самолета, вынес его на первый план?** Потому что это  особый административный самолет (бизнес-самолет, (жарг.) бизнес-джет, jet — реактивный),   предназначенный **для перевозки официальных лиц государственных учреждений и коммерческих организаций.**

Салоны таких самолетов бывают рассчитаны на количество пассажиров от 6 до 20. Они оборудованы комфортабельнее, чем обычные самолеты, и там обычно есть возможность работать на электронных устройствах, чтобы пассажиры могли не отрываться от работы на время перелёта.

http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2672073-kakoj-samoljot-nazyvajut-dzhet-pochemu.html

А вот сама история (сообщение):

*Бизнес-джет Cessna 680 едва не разбился в петербургском аэропорту Пулково.   Летчики заходили на посадку на высокой скорости, самолет коснулся земли слишком близко к концу взлетно-посадочной полосы. Когда они поняли, что рискуют не успеть вовремя остановить самолет, командир воздушного судна запросил разрешение у диспетчера уйти на взлет.*

5) **И что тут извращенного?**

Вот мнение автора вопроса: "Почему это кажется извращенным? Потому что в тексте самое важное ставится в конце предложения".

Но откуда такие сведения? **Мне это утверждение не представляется корректным.**

**Ударение** совершенно необязательно делается на последнем слове интонационной фразы, в данном случае оно делается на слове ***не разбИлся, Пулково*** здесь просто уточняет место посадки.

Comment: Слово "извращённый" (при всей эмоциональности выбора) было употреблено в значении "неестественный" (словарное значение 2). Неестественно отклонение порядка слов от нейтрального в ситуации, когда вся информация нова для адресата. Так, в сообщении о пожаре акцент в силу порядка слов сделан на _месте_ пожара, будто о _факте_ пожара адресату уже известно (= тот самый сильный пожар произошёл не где-нибудь, а там-то). Такой порядок слов был бы нормальным напр. после рассуждений о том, что "нынче повсюду происходят пожары разной интенсивности".

Comment: К сожалению, не могу согласиться.  Неверно рассуждение об акцентах как известных или неизвестных. Автор волен выбирать тему и рему по своему усмотрению,  вторая часть НЕ АКЦЕНТИРУЕТСЯ, она отнюдь не важнее первой. Каждый случай индивидуален. Ничего читателю неизвестно о пожаре заранее, но тема крупного пожара  всегда ему интересна, поэтому это и есть ТЕМА (первая часть).. Наше внимание остановлено на теме, а затем следует указание на место пожара. Всё естественно,  иначе и быть не может. А тему "в центре Москвы" ваше сознание  может оставить без внимания, так как много чего там случается.

Comment: @Sharon: Вы некорректно разбираете предложения. В предложении сначала идет тема, потом рема. В случае "Бизнес-джет едва не разбился в Пулково" тема (контекст) - это "Бизнес-джет едва не разбился". А рема (сообщение, самое главное) - это "в Пулково". Вы неправильно понимаете тема - рема, пэтому и не замечаете проблемы с порядком слов.

Comment: @Sharon: Чисто технически порядок может быть почти любым. Я же не об этом. Я о том, что в последнее время очень часто порядок слов, особенно в заголовке, проиворечит смыслу всего последующего текста.

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть только гипотеза. Такой порядок слов характерен для английского языка. Например, нейтральное положение обстоятельства времени там в конце предложения, а если для акцентирования его переносят в начало, то после него требуется запятая. Журналисты, занимающиеся подборкой новостей, часто пользуются англоязычными источниками. Многие из них не владеют техникой перевода и бессознательно переносят подобный порядок слов в собственную русскую речь. Иногда и сознательно подражают (им это кажется возможностью продемонстрировать свои познания в английском), например, ставя прозвище между именем и фамилией или употребляя заглавную букву в середине слова. Вы совершенно правильно переводите с *их русского* на русский.

Comment: Мне тоже кажется, что русскоговорящие так написать не могут. Вполне возможно, что это ПЛОХОЙ автоматизированный перевод с английского. Жаль, что даже на крупных сайтах, с хорошим финансовым положением нет редакторов, которые бы такие извращенные предложение корректировали бы. Эти примеры - с Ленты.ру. Т.е. и на Ленте нет нормальных редакторов.

Comment: @Fedor Gromov, как русскоговорящий (и, смею надеяться, неплохо владеющий языком), заверяю вас, что русскоговорящие так писать могут, так пишут, и более того, считают такое написание вполне нормальным. Вы исходите из неверной посылки, которая никак не сочетается с реальностью, но вместо того, чтобы признать это, пытаетесь скорректировать реальность под свои воззрения. Отсюда и проистекают фантазии, что русскоговорящие так не пишут, или совершенно сюрреалистическое утверждение, что самое важное надо писать в конце предложения. Ну что тут можно сказать? Успехов в перестройке мира.

Comment: @freim: Ну объясните мне тогда, почему Вы используете именно такой порядок слов в Вашем комменте: *"Вы исходите из неверной посылки"*. Почему не *"Из неверной посылки исходите Вы"*. Вот здесь, например, хорошо объясняется: https://www.sinykova.ru/spravochnik-rozental/styli_xlii/  - *... целенаправленность высказывания, его коммуникативное задание ... предполагает движение мысли от известного, знакомого к неизвестному, новому ...* И построение всех Ваших предложений соответствует этому принципу. Но в моих примерах Вы этого почему-то не видите. Очень противоречивый у Вас подход.

Comment: @Fedor Gromov, я уже ответил вам выше, что это типичный журналистский приём. В обычной речи выглядел бы странно. Конечно я его не использую здесь, это же не заметка в газете. Всему своё место, в общем.

Comment: @freim: Зачем тогда вообще грамматика в языке? Зачем порядок слов нужен? Можно просто перечислить ключевые слова, как тэги. Тогда порядок не будет иметь значения. Давайте новый прием введем журналистский: *Пулково бизнес-джет едва разбился не в*. Мне кажется, называть это журналистским приемом неправильно. Это как если б заголовок в статье был *С понедельника отменяются все органичения по вирусу*, а сам текст наоборот, о введении пропусков. Давайте назовем это тоже журналистским приемом. Мне кажется, это не прием, а просто косноязычие людей, не знающих и не чувствующих языка.

Answer (score 0):

**Второй ответ**

Мой первый ответ автор вопроса не прочитал или не заметил. Вот со всеми поговорил, поспорил, а со мной нет. (Ведь обычно обменяешься с человеком несколькими фразами и сразу понимаешь, насколько он *в теме*). Наверное, поэтому я опять вспомнила про этот вопрос, и **показался он мне странным.**

1) **Как утверждает автор, "в тексте самое важное ставится в конце предложения".**

**Интересно, откуда это, может быть, из психологии?** Именно психологи рекомендуют самое важное говорить в конце разговора, тогда это хорошо запомнится. Интересный маневр! Хотя к структурной грамматике он отношения не имеет, но люди этому утверждению поверят безоговорочно, так как когда-то  его уже слышали.

2) А теперь о названии вопроса: **Извращенный порядок слов на многих сайтах.**

*Извращенный порядок* —  **необычное, эффектное**  сочетание (учитывая, что есть более скромные синонимы), сразу привлекает внимание. Кто-то оспорит, кто-то согласится, но **заметят все.**

Но почему же автор (согласно своей теории) **сам не поставил свое самое важное (ключевое) слово  в конец фразы**, например: *Почему на некоторых сайтах используется извращенный порядок слов*?

И вот тогда начинаешь думать:  а может быть, всё это **умелый розыгрыш?** Может, в действительности автор знает всё о правильных названиях тем на новостных сайтах, но зачем тогда спрашивает?

Но это так, **рабочая гипотеза**.

Comment: Извините, не думал, что слово "извращенный" привлечет столько внимания. Считайте, что это эмоциональная окраска :) Можете интрепретировать это слово как "некорректный". Суть вопроса в том, что 1) Смысл предложения в значительной степени задается порядком слов; 2) Во многих статьях смысл заголовка противоречит смыслу самого текста. Авторитетных ссылок у меня нет. Собственно, поэтому и вопрос. Вот единственный линк, который у меня есть на эту тему: https://www.sinykova.ru/spravochnik-rozental/styli_xlii/.

Answer (score 0):

> извращенный порядок слов

На мой взгляд оба варианта корректны во всех трёх примерах.

> Потому что в тексте самое важное ставится в конце предложения.

Напротив, самое важное стоит в начале.

> 1. Написано: "Крупный пожар случился в центре Москвы"
>      Правильно: "В центре Москвы случился крупный пожар"

Да мало ли чего происходит в центре Москвы ежедневно? А вот пожар - что-то уникальное, на что стоит обратить внимание - его и поставили в начало.

> 2. Написано: "Самолет разбился во время тушения лесного пожара во Франции"
>      Правильно: "Во время тушения лесного пожара во Франции разбился самолет"

То же самое. Важно событие - что произошло, а не при каких условиях. Разбился самолёт. Как? Во время тушения пожара.

> 3. Написано: "Бизнес-джет едва не разбился в Пулково"
>      Правильно: "В Пулково едва не разбился бизнес-джет"

Опять же, мне не интересно, что происходит в Пулково. А вот что чуть не разбился очередной самолёт, особенно если он того же производителя, что и в нашумевшей аварии - вероятно интересно.

> почему на многих сайтах появился такой безграмотный извращенный стиль?

Потому что в начало заголовка надо поставить то, что заинтересует читателя, а не бесполезную информацию. Из новостей "произошёл пожар", "разбился самолёт", "едва не разбился самолёт" выбирать можно, а из новостей "в центре Москвы", "во Франции", "в Пулково" - да лесом их все.

Comment: @Qweriy: Я не про то, что формально почти любой порядок в руссом возможен. Я про то, что от порядка зависит смысл. Вы говорите *на что стоит обратить внимание - его и поставили в начало*. Вот как раз с этим я не согласен. Вот, например, ссылка, которая объясняет связь порядка слов со смыслом: https://www.sinykova.ru/spravochnik-rozental/styli_xlii/    *Определяющим фактором расположения слов в предложении является целенаправленность высказывания, его коммуникативное задание ... движение мысли от известного, знакомого к неизвестному, новому*.

Comment: @FedorGromov, полагаю, там речь о текстах, а не о заголовках. Есть исследования, что при просмотре веб-страниц человек читает начала строк. Соответственно, если он это начало посчитает неважным, он пропустит всю строку или абзац. В заголовке надо сразу видеть суть, а не движение мысли из начальной точки. Читаем: "крупный пожар", "самолёт", "бизнес-джет" - отлично, понятно, может быть интересно. Читаем: "в центре Москвы" - не, я не в Москве, дальше; "во Франции" - там меня тоже нет; "в Пулково" - снова мимо.